# Bootstrap col not taking full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've used `col-xs-3` and `col-xs-9` for my 2 col. However the form doesn't seem to take up all the space on the right. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: can you put your code here https://jsfiddle.net/devefrontend/21036h5c/

Comment: we need to see your code. on image we cant help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
    <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.